# Scala 3: "assertion failed: denotation class Int invalid in run 1."

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am calling Scala 3's compiler as a library, which gives you `CompilationUnit` per source after compilation. This has `tpdTree`, which by the sound of it should contain type information.

I'm trying to walk the tree to get any type symbol as:

```scala
 atPhase(Phases.typerPhase.next) {
   // traverse unit.tpdTree...
 }
```

Where tree walking looks like:

```scala
  class ValExtractor(tpes: Set[String]) extends tpd.TreeTraverser:
    def isAcceptableType(tpe: Types.Type)(using ctx: Context): Boolean =
      tpe.baseClasses.exists { sym =>
        tpes.contains(sym.fullName.toString)
      }
    override def traverse(tree: tpd.Tree)(using ctx: Context): Unit =
      tree match
        case tpd.ValDef(name, tpt, _) if isAcceptableType(tpt.tpe) =>
          println("do something")
        case t: tpd.Template   => this((), t.body)
        case t: tpd.PackageDef => this((), t.stats)
        case t: tpd.TypeDef    => this((), t.rhs)
        case _                 => ()
  end ValExtractor
```

I get

```scala
[info]   assertion failed: denotation class Int invalid in run 1. ValidFor: Period(1..55, run = 2)
[info]     scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:8)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.updateValidity(Denotations.scala:719)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.bringForward(Denotations.scala:744)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.toNewRun$1(Denotations.scala:803)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.current(Denotations.scala:877)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols$Symbol.recomputeDenot(Symbols.scala:122)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols$Symbol.computeDenot(Symbols.scala:116)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols$Symbol.denot(Symbols.scala:109)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols$.toDenot(Symbols.scala:502)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.updateValidity(Denotations.scala:718)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.bringForward(Denotations.scala:744)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.toNewRun$1(Denotations.scala:803)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$SingleDenotation.current(Denotations.scala:877)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$NamedType.computeDenot(Types.scala:2253)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$NamedType.denot(Types.scala:2213)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$NamedType.info(Types.scala:2201)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$TypeRef.underlying(Types.scala:2693)
[info]     dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$Type.baseClasses(Types.scala:600)
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Resolution

In my case I had `(using ctx: Context)` in my method, but apparently that did not match the run context. Passing it explicitly as follows fixed it:

```scala
atPhase(Phases.typerPhase.next) {
  (new ValExtractor(valTypes.toSet)).getVals(unit.tpdTree)
}(using run.runContext)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the query in a context where the `run` value is the same as when the definitions were created (or is a later run, but an earlier run is not valid).

The error message you are seeing is that you ask about a denotation of a symbol at run 1, which is conceptually before it was created at run 2.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxyyJyB_Ssc for a video where the run/phase concept is explained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Passing in the context explicitly fixed it:

```
atPhase(Phases.typerPhase.next) {
  (new ValExtractor(valTypes.toSet)).getVals(unit.tpdTree)
}(using run.runContext)
```